# PostSharp - logger as an aspect argument

Tags: c#, attributes, postsharp

Want to use **PostSharp** diagnostics with an aspect for exception handling encapsulated in a library assembly.

At the same time trying to setup and initialize a **Serilog logger** in the consumer assembly of that diagnostics library.

```
[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Order, AspectDependencyPosition.After,
  typeof(AddContextOnExceptionAttribute))]
[PSerializable]
public sealed class ReportAndSwallowExceptionAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public ILogger TheLogger { get; set; }

    public ReportAndSwallowExceptionAttribute(ILogger logger)
    {
        TheLogger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        TheLogger.Error("Error happened ...");
    }
 }
```

In the main class:

```
    class Program
    {
        // below line is the critical part which seems ILogger is not allowed
        [ReportAndSwallowException(Log.Logger)]
        public static void TryExceptionMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.File(@"HERE\Logs\log-x.log", 
                     rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                     .CreateLogger();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            TryExceptionMethod();

        }    

    }
```

Seems passing `ILogger` to that attribute is illegal, how can I achieve this scenario?

**Current Error:**

```
Error   CS0181: Attribute constructor parameter 'logger' has type 'ILogger', which is not a valid attribute parameter type
```

Think this error needs a constant to be solved, but the main question is how to achieve this scenario: have the logger in the consumer proj, have the aspects in a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option here is that your aspect directly references Log.Logger.

There are several other more complex options that are documented here: https://doc.postsharp.net/consuming-dependencies

Comment: Thanks +1 Gael, can you please let me know how can I reference Log.Logger in the aspect library? As I know the aspect library doesn't know about its consumers and currently don't know exactly how you mean I can accomplish this.

Comment: And about the more complex options will study those links.

Comment: Also if you back, please kindly let me know which approach you suggest among the complex options.

Comment: Not sure if I get you correctly about the first option, by referencing Log.Logger if you mean to place it directly in the aspect library, guess it will destroy the whole scenario, imagine each consumer will have its own log files and setup, what could we do with it then? passing the log location as an argument also can't help cause, on any exception the aspect will create a new logger.

Comment: Ah, got it. You would need the static field to be in an assembly accessible from ReportAndSwallowException. I would go with the simplest option if that works for you, which is the public static field. Then I would go for a global service locator.